# How can I use a Child component instead of a template in ngbTabSet?

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

The [ngbTabSet](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs) has a 'template' and that's where the content is declared. Instead of that template, how can I use another Child component? Is that possible?

Comment: What is the problem? Did you try `<template ngbTabContent><my-child></my-child></template>`? https://plnkr.co/edit/wv2EK7ZhAfk51X6mWklB?p=preview

Comment: It works with the template as you described above. But using <my-child> directly inside the <ngb-tab title="Simple"> is what I'm looking for.